# visual c++ - missing unrelated DLLs

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

I just brought a project I was working on from linux with cmake and g++ to windows visual studio. I just copied the source files and did some changes to the code to fit windows and got the code to compile on windows. My problem is that when I try to run it it gives me missing dll run time errors. At first it gave me libgmp-10.dll missing which seems to be for minGW or gcc. I downloaded that one and put it besides my executable. Now it says libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing. Aren't these dlls for gcc? Shouldn't visual studio not need these?

Comment: libgmp sounds like a GMP DLL.  (Gnu Multiprecision Library).  If that's the case, you still need it for Visual C++.  It is *not* a Visual C++ runtime library, which is what may be confusing you.  https://gmplib.org/

Comment: How did you compile your project? What generator used in cmake? What library you linked to your project?

Answer (score 1):

Check with liner->input options. It might be referring to .libs of these dlls. Replace them with windows equivalents.